# In Magento 2 How to remove the "Position" option from the Sort by Toolbar

Tags: magento2

I've been trying to remove the Sort by "Position"  option. Can we do it without extending template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove it using configuration in admin

Go to Catalog>categories, On your Category edit page go on Display Settings and change the "Available Product Listing Sort By" with the Filters you want.

Comment: How can it be done for all categories?

Comment: @Alex use plugin like here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253618/how-to-remove-relevance-sort-by-in-magento-2