# How to remove relevance sort by in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to remove relevance sort by in magento 2. PFA

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento add osrt order from `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result::setAvailableOrders()` for **catalog search** page.

Create a plugin on `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result` at  `setAvailableOrders` method.

Using `around` plugin on `setAvailableOrders` and modify and update existing sort order.

**Define `di.xml` at `app\StackExchanges\OnlyMagento\etc\frontend`.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category   Stackexchange
 * @package    Stackexchange
 * @author     Amit Bera<dev.amitbera@gmail.com>
 * @website    http://www.amitbera.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
        <plugin name="remove_relevance_search"
                type="StackExchanges\OnlyMagento\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Block\ResultPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin class `ResultPlugin.php` at `app\code\StackExchanges\OnlyMagento\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Block`.**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   Stackexchange
 * @package    Stackexchange
 * @author     Amit Bera<dev.amitbera@gmail.com>
 * @website    http://www.amitbera.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

namespace StackExchanges\OnlyMagento\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;

class ResultPlugin {

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
     */
    protected $catalogLayer; 

    public function __construct(
      LayerResolver $layerResolver      
    ) {

        $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();             
    }

    public function aroundSetListOrders(
        \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result $subject,
        \Closure $proceed       
    )
    {
        $category = $this->catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
        /* @var $category \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category */
        $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
        unset($availableOrders['position']);

        $subject->getListBlock()->setAvailableOrders(
            $availableOrders
        )->setDefaultDirection(
            'desc'
        )->setDefaultSortBy(
            $category->getDefaultSortBy()
        );

        return $subject;
    }
}
```

**Note that code is not tested. The code is posted here based on the idea.**